# How to get key usage of a digital certificate in java

Tags: java, certificate, digital-signature, digital-certificate

How to get key usage of a digital certificate in java. 
I want to know the use of purpose of a certificate like digital signature or key-encipherment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get that information by calling the [`X509Certificate.getKeyUsage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getKeyUsage--) method.

Extended key usage information can be obtained from [`X509Certificate.getExtendedKeyUsage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getExtendedKeyUsage--).

Comment: thanks , but I want the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129475/get-the-key-usage-from-certificate using java.

Comment: I just gave you the answer. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Ok , please provide me some hints to identify the purpose of certificate.

Comment: As I said, you can get this information by calling the aforementioned methods. The linked javadoc nicely explains how to interpret the output. I really don't understand what your issue is.

Comment: this is giving me no of boolean values.How to identify the one purpose.

Comment: It's specified in the javadoc. Click [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getKeyUsage--). Read explanation. Parse accordingly. There's not necessarily only one purpose. There might be multiple.

Comment: thanks for this  helpful information. I am using e-token that has two certificate. both certificates key usage property are same.but I think they should be different.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see basic information about a certificate, keytool would do the trick:

```
keytool -printcert -file <mycert.cer>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I want java code to do this.